# Laravel Eloquent Date Formatting

Tags: php, laravel

Having to make this post before I go insane, as none of the solutions I can find online are working.

My Laravel application isn't returning the right data because Laravel seems to be 'INSISTING' on using "m/d/Y" as the date format when running the query. My code is below...

```
$now = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");
$previousTime = (new DateTime($now))->modify('-1 minutes')->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
$count = PlayLog::where('user_id', 1)->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $previousTime)->get()->count();
```

The data is stored in the database as d/m/Y, but Laravel is querying m/d/Y. How can I fix this?

**UPDATE
I am official mad now, but the answer is whereDate() doesn't support time :/**

Comment: Are you using the default `created_at` column? I.e. does you migration use `$table->timestamps()`? If so, the format is `Y-m-d h:i:s`, not `d/m/Y`. If you're using a custom implementation of `created_at`, then you should share your migration, and a snippet if your database so so we can attempt to recreate/debug this.

Comment: Hi Tim, yes it's the standard created_at using $table->timestamps(). I also tried that date format too, doesn't seems to work either. I just want to return results which were created in the last minute :(

Comment: Just saw your question edit. I was gonna suggest it might have something to do with `whereDate()` :) If you've figured your issue out, feel free to add a self-answer and accept it (when the system allows) to benefit other users who have the same issue, and properly close your question.

Comment: Because of this kind of mess I had to store all dates as Unix timestamps in one of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can take leverage of [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Import `use Carbon\Carbon;`

Date formatting via carbon to match your DB
`$previousDT = Carbon::now()->addDay(-2)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'); // 10/05/2020 23:05:06
PlayLog::whereDate('created_at', '>=', $previousDT)`